Docker compose is not creating creating tables in Database
I am learing Docker and encountered an error is that I have created a basic CRUD springboot application which create,getById and getAll Users then configure the Dockerfile and then docker-compose.yml. once I run docker-compose up,  its starts creating images and containers and I can see that they are running perfectly ( the status is running ) but they are not creating  user tables in MySQL or in simple it is not running the Springboot application just running dockerfile and docker-compose.yml..
Dockerfile

FROM openjdk:21
LABEL authors="MohammedKhadeer"
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY . /usr/src/myapp/
#ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","./target/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
CMD ["java", "-jar","./target/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

docker-compose.yml
services:
  mydb:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_database_latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE = docker-testing
      - MYSQL_USER =  admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD =  root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD =  root
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3333:3306
    networks:
      - myapplication
  myapp:
    build: ./docker
    container_name: docker_boot_app
    depends_on:
      - mydb
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mydb:3306/docker-testing?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      - spring.datasource.username=admin
      - spring.datasource.password=root
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    networks:
      - myapplication
networks:
  myapplication:


application.property

spring.application.name=docker

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/docker-testing
#spring.datasource.username=admin
#spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true




Why should it be creating the user table? Where are your create table statements stored?

What do the logs of your spring boot container say? I'd start by looking there.

I would also recommend NOT running your Spring app in Docker initially to make sure it is actually behaving as you expect it to.

I also attach the screenshot of the console now. But it says nothing in it. The strange thing is,its not even running the @RestController when I am calling the String as a endpoint
`  @RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public String Welcome(){
    return "welcome here";
} `


Your app is not creating the tables because spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is set to update, which only updates the existing schema.
If you want to create the tables you need to set the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property to create or create-drop.
create - will create the tables if they don't exists.
create-drop - will create tables when app is up and drop then when app is shutdown.
Another important configuration is:
spring.jpa.generate-ddl
This configuration tells spring jpa that ddl is enabled to execute. The default value for this property is false, so you need to explicitly set it to true.
Documentation reference for database initialization in spring boot 2.7.x: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.18-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization

I even tried spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create or create-drop but nothing happened.

Can you edit the question with the configuration files you have to make the datasource and also which dependencies you are using for the mysql (spring starters, mysql connectors, etc)?

I used the stater dependencies: web,data-jpa,mysql driver(mysql-connector-j)

Ok! So one more question: have you tried to set spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true?

In the Docker file, you are telling docker to run the jar file from the target
folder. Each time you make a change to your Java files you have to rebuild this file with Maven. Try running mvn package and give it another chance.
To avoid doing this every time, you can tell docker to run mvn package as well.
HOPE THIS HELPS

Your docker-compose.yml is wrong. As far as I know to set application properties in Spring Boot by using an environment variable it takes a special naming convention.
For example: spring.datasource.url becomes SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL.
Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config
